# $(this).addClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do `$(this).children("a").addClass("class")` and it works fine, but when I do `$(this).addClass("class")` it is not working.  I am using `$(this)` within a mouseover function.

```
$("#site nav li.hasChild").mouseover(function ()
{
    $(this).children("a").addClass("selectedTab");  // works fine
    $(this).addClass("selectedFixTab"); // does not work
    $(this).children("ul").css("display", "block");
});
```

HTML:

```
<header id="site">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="Li1" class="hasChild">
                <a href="#">Fix</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="Li2" class="hasChild">
                <a href="#">Learn</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="Li3">
                <a href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.selectedFixTab
{
    border-top:1px solid #eb7c00;
    border-left:1px solid #eb7c00;
    border-right:1px solid #eb7c00;
}

.selectedLearnTab
{
    border-top:1px solid #2d70a3;
    border-left:1px solid #2d70a3;
    border-right:1px solid #2d70a3;
}

.selectedTab
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  See it in action here, cut and paste: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/4Q5mg/

Comment: @Dan Clash. What browser you are used for checks? Maybe it does not support multiple CSS classes?

Comment: Just a general tip -- add console.log($(this)) OR console.log(this.className) , you will know what you are selecting / its class name .

Comment: @Andrew I seriously doubt that he'd use IE 4 or Netscape Navigator.

Comment: I am using IE 9, but need it to work in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I am not even able to set a class on the li tag.  I can set the border via $("#site nav li.hasChild").css("boder", "1px solid black"), but if I use the following $("#site nav li.hasChild").addClass("selectedFixTab") which just has the border set it doesn't work.  Any ideas why the li tag won't take the class via jquery.  If I add the class in the html it works fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

It successfully adds the `"selectedFixTab"` class to the top level LI tags as soon as the mouse hovers over the LI tag.  You can see it in action here in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mj2u6/.

I'm not sure it's doing exactly what you intend, but it is doing what the code says to do.  If you care to explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can likely help you fix the code to do what you want.

Comment: I need to add a class to the parent li as well as the child a so that is why I had the mouseover on the li and then could select the child a tag.

Comment: Is there still a question you need help with?

Comment: I figured out the issue.  The border was set to white in another class so it wasn't showing up for me.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#site nav li a").mouseover(function ()
{
    $(this).children("a").addClass("selectedTab");  // works fine
    $(this).addClass("selectedFixTab"); // does not work
    $(this).children("ul").css("display", "block");
});
```

I think this is what you want it to do!

Comment: Why select an `a` and then it's `a` children?

Comment: I left that in the OP's code so he can recognize it. But I think he wants to add a class to the <a> when the mouse hovers the <li>.